# Jruby thread context instance association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, threadcontext

I am trying to eval javascript in ruby.

```
config/initializer/initializer_context.rb
  js_str = 
  EXEC_PP_CONTEXT = ExecJS.compile("function test_add(param) { return param.a+ param.b;}")
```

and then in my controller I am using :

```
data_hash = {:a=>4,:b=>5}
EXEC_PP_CONTEXT.exec("return test_add(#{data_hash.to_json})")
```

But I occasionally get this error ( 1 in 100 requests)

```
can not use Context instance already associated with some thread
```

Stack:

- jruby-1.7.3 in ruby 1.9 mode
- trinidad server with jruby_min_runtimes & jruby_min_runtimes as 1
- rails 3.2.13
- therubyrhino 2.0.2

If I am already setting max runtime and min runtime to 1 shouldn't it avoid this problem in first place ?

Comment: it's probably coming from Rhino itself not JRuby - uses a context per thread to manage state as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out by reading Mozilla rhino's code:
https://github.com/matthieu/rhymeno/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.java#LC416

`static final Context enter(Context cx, ContextFactory factory)` Basically the method counts the number of threads that are inside the context ( using it / executing it) and if another thread tries to enter it , it throws an error.

To avoid the problem and achieve concurrency , we lazily created one context per thread using ruby's `Thread[:current][:some_js_context] = blah_`

Comment: since you already answered on your own you should also change the title to somehow better reflect what this q is about ...